# How to resolv to create resource dimen.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm working on  Android SDK 3.0. In my main layout XML Text I've got thisAll @dimen are in error :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
.../...
```

I created the `res/values/dimen.xml` file but I don't know how to configure the values above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="action_button_min_width">56dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="indeterminate_progress_size">32dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

The documentation in the developer.android.com site is very light.

Thanks

Comment: You can check my answer .Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

You should create **res/values/dimens.xml** file

Use `dimens.xml` in your `res/values/` folder .

When you put empty in `dimens.xml` code , there is no problem compiling the program .

But it will cause the problem when you **run the app** .

> Error:(812, 69) String types not allowed (at 'activity_vertical_margin' with value '').

You can use `<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">0dp</dimen>` as default value .

It must add value in the `dimen` .

Comment: Yes I put empty values to <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin"></dimen> and <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin"></dimen> the compilation passed well

Comment: Yes.It compile well .But it will cause `Error:(812, 69) String types not allowed (at 'activity_vertical_margin' with value '').`  in your code .So you can use ` <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">0dp</dimen>` in your code .